# Is a custom hook the best solution?

Tags: css, reactjs

I'm making a simple chess app and wanted the board size to responsively fill the window while remaining square (width = height). I ended up making my first custom hook, and it works well, but I wanted to know if there are better solutions to  this problem.
My hook:

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

const getDimensions = () => {
  return document.documentElement.clientWidth > document.documentElement.clientHeight
    ? { boardSize: "100vh", pieceSize: "10vh"}
    : { boardSize: "100vw", pieceSize: "10vw"};
};

function useDimensions() {
  let [dimensions, setDimensions] = useState(getDimensions());
  useEffect(() => {
    const handleResize = () => {
      setDimensions(getDimensions());
    };
    window.addEventListener("resize", handleResize);
    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener("resize", handleResize);
    };
  }, []);
  return dimensions;
}

export default useDimensions;
```

In my board component I simply `let boardSize = useDimensions().boardSize;` and then reference boardSize in the jsx style.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `{ boardSize: "100vmin", pieceSize: "10vmin"}` and be done without any js.

> `vmin`
> Equal to the smaller of `vw` and `vh`.

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/length#vmin

Comment: Wow, I had no idea about vmin, thanks so much!